# How do I get the event source element

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, variables

I'm trying to keep my JS modular for easier readability and generalized, however I am having trouble getting the `$(this)` of the `checkboxButton.on("click")` to make define the variable `checkboxSelected`.

How do I make a global variable from within a function() (if that is the right way of putting it)?

```js
var checkboxButton = $("[data-checkbox-id]"),
    checkboxContainer = checkboxButton.parent();

function checkboxRadio() {

    var checkboxSelected = $(this).attr("data-checkbox-id");
    console.log(checkboxSelected);

    checkboxSelected.attr("aria-checked","true");

    if (!$('[data-checkbox-id="' + checkboxSelected +'"]')) {
        checkboxButton.attr("aria-checked","false");
    }
}


function checkboxInit() {
    console.log("Checkbox Initialised");

    checkboxButton.on("touchend click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // Check the checkbox type
        if (checkboxContainer.attr("data-checkbox-type") == "radio") {
            checkboxRadio();
        } else {
            // checkboxMultiple();
        }
    });

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset data-checkbox-type="radio">
    <label>Gender</label>
    <button class="checkbox-radio" value="male" name="male" aria-checked="true" data-checkbox-id="1">
        <span class="icon-checkbox"></span>
        No
    </button>
    <button class="checkbox-radio" value="female" name="female" aria-checked="false" data-checkbox-id="2">
        <span class="icon-checkbox"></span>
        Yes
    </button>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Can you be little more clear of what exactly you want the output to be

Comment: I *think* you are looking for `checkboxRadio.call(this)`.

Comment: Send along `this` when you call the function: **(1)** `checkboxRadio(this);` **(2)** `function checkboxRadio(btn) {` **(3)** `var checkboxSelected=$(btn).attr("data-checkbox-id");`

Comment: Instead of `.attr("data-checkbox-type")` I'd recommend using `.data("checkbox-type")`.

Comment: @FelixKling - I clearly still have so much to learn.. didn't even know about this. What exactly is the downside of my solution (one comment after yours), as opposed to yours? *(One benefit I can see of your solution is that you don't have to declare an argument in the invoked function, meaning you can call it from other places without specifying `this`, but are there more reasons?)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send along `this` when you call the function:

1. `checkboxRadio(this);`
2. `function checkboxRadio(btn) {`
3. `var checkboxSelected = $(btn).attr("data-checkbox-id");`

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the bind method before calling it like this:

`checkboxRadio.bind(this)();`

Basically what it does is: you're saying to the method your calling the context of the `this` variable.

So, when you do `checkboxRadio.bind(this)();` the method `checkboxRadio` will know that the `this` variable is the button that you just clicked.

For more information about the bind method you can find it here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind